# Styling parts of a string

Tags: jquery

I would like to style differently two parts of a price tag. I'd like to make the dollar amount larger than the cents. The price is a dynamic value, so I'd have to wrap each part separately. How do I do that?

```
var price = "12.95";

// desired result
<span class="dollar">12.</span><span class="cents">95</span>
```

I don't suppose I could use just CSS, but I'll be OK with throwing some jQuery.

Comment: So you are saying you don't have control over the HTML or something. Your HTML above looks fine, just style the CSS for each span how you want. Why would you need javascript at all?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Oh he was trying to figure out how to break apart the price. Man sometimes the questions on here are so hard to figure out just what they are asking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try splitting the price by `.` seperator and then append the tags like below,

```
var priceTokens = price.split('.');
price = '<span class="dollar">' + priceTokens[0] + 
        '</span><span class="cents">.' + priceTokens[1] + '</span>';
```

Answer (score 3):

`split()` the string on the period.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

```
var price = '12.95';
var arr = price.split(".");

var dollar = arr[0];
var cent = arr[1];

// desired result
var str = '<span class="dollar">' + arr[0] + 
          '</span><span class="cents">' + arr[1] +'</span>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Something different:

```
var price = '12.95'.split('.');
$('<span/>').appendTo('body').addClass('dollar').html('$' + price[0]);
$('<span/>').appendTo('body').addClass('cents').html('.' + price[1]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WRrR7/1/